# Lookup field and Invalid data has been used to update the list item error

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I have list A with three columns JobNumber,Crew and Date which is lookup column to List B. When I create three individual lookup fields in List B then following code works fine,

```
SP.FieldLookupValue lvjobNum = new SP.FieldLookupValue();
lvjobNum.LookupId = ID;
lItem["JobNumber"] = lvjobNum;

SP.FieldLookupValue lvCrew = new SP.FieldLookupValue();
lvCrew.LookupId = ID;
lItem["Crew"] = lvCrew;

SP.FieldLookupValue lvDate = new SP.FieldLookupValue();
lvDate.LookupId = ID;
lItem["Date"] = lvDate;
```

However when I create lookup field using "Additional column settings" option like,

[image]

Then same code shown above doesn't work and it throws an error,

```
<nativehr>0x80070057</nativehr><nativestack></nativestack>Invalid data has been used to update the list item. The field you are trying to update may be read only.
```

Any idea ?

Comment: Please add your solution as an answer and mark it as accepted so this question is no longer considered unanswered.

Answer (score 0):

(Answered by the OP as an edit to the question. Transcribed here as a community wiki answer. See [Question with no answers, but issue solved in the comments (or extended in chat)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments) )

The OP wrote:

> Fix was simple,

```
SP.FieldLookupValue flvRDS = new SP.FieldLookupValue();
flvRDS.LookupId = ID;
lItem["RDS"] = flvRDS;
```